# three js crushing on chrome android

Tags: google-chrome, three.js, webgl

Im trying to open this link http://3dhd.co.il/mobile/170 in my chrome browser in samsung galaxy s6, and after about 2 minutes the browser crushes and im getting the message "Rats Web GL hit a snag".

I've tried following the chrome instruction (clear cookies etc), tried enabling the flags in chrome://flags.

How can i debug this problem and understand why is it happening,
i developed that scene, and i cant understand what i have done wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried loading it in chrome and checking the console log? Massive amount of errors and logs

Comment: the errors are just some 3d models that the script cant find, but can it be that logs that im seeing in the console are the cause of the crush?

Comment: I dare say it's the complexity of your scene. as an example, your scene has over 700,000 instances of THREE.Vector3, and over 700 instances of THREE.Mesh. Atleast.. that's what chrome dev tools seems to be indicating.

Comment: On first look there is a overlap.Effect indicate high poly .Its just not optimised for mobile platforms.

Comment: @NikolaLukic , i upgraded to r83. so most of the errors and warning are gone. can u please explain to me ur comment? i dont understand what it means. what is overlap effect? and how can i optimize my project for mobile  platforms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's Suggestion .

Overlap vertices example :

[image: Screenshot]

It means that 3d mesh object is complex . Try to use blender ( free software ) open 3d object (import) click  to enter edit mode . Then you can see numbers of vertex point. Best optimization for this example is to make convex optimise .

Also check materials !

See this answer : 
[Three.js project crashes mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33696382/three-js-project-crashes-mobile)

Look at : 
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6253/how-to-convert-from-high-poly-to-low-poly

[image]